# i2c port change randomly

Tags: udev, devices, i2c, i2cdetect

I'm  using an Up squared computer.
I connect a device via the i2c port in the HAT connector.
When using `i2cdetect` I detect the same device (identified by the address) on different ports. Changes occur between  reboots.

To my understanding, I may be able to resolve this by setting a rule in `etc/udev/rules.d`, but I'm not sure how to do this. Specifically, I'm not sure how to filter the sensor to create the rule.
The `kernel` I see is `i2c-2`, but I wonder if this will change on the next reboot.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same problem with you when I work with seeed ODYSSEY board.
I worked it out by add a rule file 71-i2c.rules to /etc/udev/rules.d/

The detail code of 71-i2c.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="i2c-dev", KERNELS=="i2c_designware.1", SYMLINK+="i2c-10"
```

I use this code to create a symlink to the specific i2c I want.
And I can alway get the correct data by operate on /dev/i2c-10.

How to get the specific data of the i2c bus you want?
You can get it by this command:

```
udevadm info -a /dev/i2c-1
```

In the output of this command, you need to find the specific data that only the
i2c bus you want having.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the i2c number is assigned dynamically so it could change. As a result, I don't think you can use it statically.

Comment: Do you have a link to a definitive reference? If so please [edit] and add it to the answer.